# Database locks on content database. How to identify what is generating the statement SharePoint side?

Tags: sql-server

We're currently experiencing database locks on our one of our site collection's content database. These locks are generated by the SharePoint web server, and shows up in the Activity Monitor in MS SQL Studio as a 'SELECT' statement by our service account. It seems to occur through users using a heavily relied on list on the site collection. Nature of it will be that when users try save, it will hang, and then of course investigation reveals that there's a database lock blocking the 'INSERT' statements.

What I need to try do is identify which user on SharePoint, or what service, is generating this statement and causing the issue. Once it reaches the SQL database it just shows up as coming from the service account and web server, which makes it difficult to identify the true root.

I'm not a SharePoint administrator, and have limited experience. As a result, any help is truly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: This sound like a classic thresehold problem. Head over to central admin >  Application Management -> Manage Web Applications > select one web application to start with and go to General Settings. From here, search for the field that sets the web applications threshold - if it's above 5000, this can be the thing causing your database locks.

Comment: http://www.abelsolutions.com/2013-blog/working-with-list-view-thresholds-in-sharepoint/

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Potentially an issue, but most people use our default view and I believe only about 200 - 300 items are being returned on average per page.